# Partial update with Spring Data Elasticsearch repository

Tags: java, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a document with many fields (some nested) indexed on elasticsearch. For example:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "username" : "...",
  "name" : "...",
  "surname" : "...",
  "address" : "...",
  "age": 42,
  ...
  "bookmarks" : [{...}, {...}],
  "tags" : [{...}, {...}]
}
```

Only some filed is mapped in my entity (I don't want to map the entire document):

```
@Document(indexName = "...", type = "...")
public class User {
  @Id
  private int id;
  private String username;
  private String address;

  // getter/setter methods

}
```

In the service class I would like to do a partial update with [ElasticsearchRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/repository/ElasticsearchRepository.java), without mapping all document's fields in the entity:

```
public class UserServiceClass {

  @Autowired
  private UserElasticsearchRepository userElasticsearchRepository;

  public void updateAddress(int id, String updatedAddress) {
    User user = userElasticsearchRepository.findOne(id);
    user.setAddress(updatedAddress);
    userElasticsearchRepository.save(user);
  } 
}
```

but ***save*** method overwrites the entire document:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "username" : "...",
  "address" : "..."
}
```

Partial udpdate seems not supported by [ElasticsearchRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/repository/ElasticsearchRepository.java). So I used [ElasticsearchTemplate](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ElasticsearchTemplate.java), to make a partial update, for example:

```
public class UserServiceClass {

  @Autowired
  private UserElasticsearchRepository userElasticsearchRepository;

  @Autowired
  private ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;

  public void updateAddress(int id, String updatedAddress) {
    User user = userElasticsearchRepository.findOne(id);
    if (user.getUsername().equals("system")) {
      return;
    }

    IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest();
    indexRequest.source("address", updatedAddress);
    UpdateQuery updateQuery = new UpdateQueryBuilder().withId(user.getId()).withClass(User.class).withIndexRequest(indexRequest).build();
    elasticsearchTemplate.update(updateQuery);
  } 
}
```

but seems a bit redundant to have two similar references (repository and ElasticsearchTemplate).

Can anyone suggest me a better solution?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of having both *ElasticsearchTemplate* and *UserElasticsearchRepository* injected into your *UserServiceClass*, you can implement your own **custom repository** and let your existing  *UserElasticsearchRepository* extend it.

I assume that your existing **UserElasticsearchRepository** look something like this.

```
public interface UserElasticsearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<User, String> {
   ....
}
```

You have to create new interface name **UserElasticsearchRepositoryCustom**. Inside this interface you can list your custom query method.

```
public interface UserElasticsearchRepositoryCustom {

    public void updateAddress(User user, String updatedAddress);

}
```

Then implement your *UserElasticsearchRepositoryCustom* by create a class called **UserElasticsearchRepositoryImpl** and implement your custom method inside with injected *ElasticsearchTemplate*

```
public class UserElasticsearchRepositoryImpl implements UserElasticsearchRepositoryCustom {

    @Autowired
    private ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;

    @Override
    public void updateAddress(User user, String updatedAddress){
        IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest();
        indexRequest.source("address", updatedAddress);
        UpdateQuery updateQuery = new UpdateQueryBuilder().withId(user.getId()).withClass(User.class).withIndexRequest(indexRequest).build();
        elasticsearchTemplate.update(updateQuery);
    }
}
```

After that, just extends your **UserElasticsearchRepository** with **UserElasticsearchRepositoryCustom** so it should look like this.

```
public interface UserElasticsearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<User, String>, UserElasticsearchRepositoryCustom {
   ....
}
```

Finally, you service code should look like this.

```
public class UserServiceClass {

  @Autowired
  private UserElasticsearchRepository userElasticsearchRepository;

  public void updateAddress(int id, String updatedAddress) {
    User user = userElasticsearchRepository.findOne(id);
    if (user.getUsername().equals("system")) {
      return;
    }
    userElasticsearchRepository.updateAddress(user,updatedAddress);
  } 
}
```

You can also move your user finding logic into the custom repository logic as well so that you can passing only user id and address in the method. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: could you please help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64771780/updating-elasticsearch-entities-with-bulk

Comment: Important: The repository infrastructure tries to autodetect custom implementation fragments by scanning for classes below the package in which it found a repository. These classes need to follow the naming convention of appending a postfix defaulting to Impl

Answer (score 1):

You can use ElasticSearchTemplate also to get your User object instead of repository interface. you can use NativeSearchQueryBuilder and other classes to build your query. With this you can avoid two similar reference from your class. Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks Shahnaz, in my final solution I've only used ElasticSearchTemplate to read and update User object. But I hope it will be possible to do also partial update with Spring Data Elasticsearch repositories.

Comment: AFAIK right now there is no partial update is available with repositories, if you find something please let me know also. Thanks